# Is z spread always ‘better’ than nominal spread?

Tags: spread, discounting, yield, callable-bonds, abs

If nominal spread is the addition to the treasury yield at the WAL of the risky bond cashflows (to worst) necessary to make the npv of the cashflows equal to a given price, and z spread is the addition to the treasury yields at each cashflow of the risky bond (to worst) to make the npv of the cashflows equal to a given price, why would anyone ever use nominal spread in any context?

Is there something I’m missing about z spread, like it has to be to maturity rather than to worst? Based on my understanding of the two terms z spread should be used, and nominal spread should never be used.